# Schedule badge update task process in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have found code on implementing batch update for awarding badges as follow. However, i have no idea on how to implement this in asp.net MVC. From what i have known, the implementation should be done in global.asax file in MVC. How should i trigger this in global.asax file?

```html
public abstract class BadgeJob
{
    protected BadgeJob()
    {
        //start cycling on initialization
        Insert();
    }

    //override to provide specific badge logic
    protected abstract void AwardBadges();

    //how long to wait between iterations
    protected abstract TimeSpan Interval { get; }

    private void Callback(string key, object value, CacheItemRemovedReason reason)
    {
        if (reason == CacheItemRemovedReason.Expired)
        {
            this.AwardBadges();
            this.Insert();
        }
    }

    private void Insert()
    {
        HttpRuntime.Cache.Add(this.GetType().ToString(),
            this,
            null,
            Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,
            this.Interval,
            CacheItemPriority.Normal,
            this.Callback);
    }
}

public class CommenterBadge : BadgeJob
{
    public CommenterBadge() : base() { }

    protected override void AwardBadges()
    {
        //select all users who have more than x comments 
        //and dont have the commenter badge
        //add badges
    }

    //run every 10 minutes
    protected override TimeSpan Interval
    {
        get { return new TimeSpan(0,10,0); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO and experience, it is not possible and advisable to do a batch job ora task from the web context. It is always recommended to do a entry in the db from the web context.the next step will be to have a windows service to take the data and process you can also refer to the Quartz.net for this task.